# Why does PhpStorm not step into my Vue component code when debugging Jest unit tests?

Tags: debugging, vue.js, phpstorm, jestjs, babeljs

I have a [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) web application for which I've written unit tests using [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) (v23.6.0).

When I debug a unit test in [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) (v2018.3.1), it breaks on breakpoints placed in my unit test code. However, when I place breakpoints in the Vue component under test, PhpStorm ignores them.

Also, when I try to step into my Vue component test from a breakpoint placed in a unit test, PhpStorm ignores and treats my "step into" instruction as if it were a "step over".

I should add that my project uses [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) (v7.0.0-beta.3) for ES6 support. Thinking the issue might derive from differences in line numbers following transpilation, I've added the following to my `.babelrc` file:

```
"sourceMaps": true,
"retainLines": true
```

Unfortunately this did not solve the issue.

Why is PhpStorm ignoring my breakpoints and how can I fix it?

Comment: can be related to having components code instrumented for coverage - it usually breaks the sourcemaps

Comment: Thanks.  But this also happens when coverage is tuned off.